# App hangs as soon as I try to call Parse LoginUI

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using the ParseLoginUI library to add login functionality to my app. Usually it works very well, but recently I deleted all backend-data via the parse web backend and now my app hangs after this code is executed:

```
ParseLoginBuilder builder = new ParseLoginBuilder(this);
        Intent parseLoginIntent = builder
                .setAppLogo(R.drawable.app_logo)
                .setParseLoginEnabled(true)
                .setParseLoginButtonText("Go")
                .setParseSignupButtonText("Register")
                .setParseLoginHelpText("Forgot password?")
                .setParseLoginInvalidCredentialsToastText("You email and/or password is not correct")
                .setParseLoginEmailAsUsername(false)
                .setParseSignupSubmitButtonText("Submit registration")
                .setFacebookLoginEnabled(true)
                .setFacebookLoginButtonText("Facebook")
                .setFacebookLoginPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"))
                .setTwitterLoginEnabled(true)
                .setTwitterLoginButtontext("Twitter")
                .build();
        startActivityForResult(parseLoginIntent, 0);
```

There is no log output.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the simulator and clearing DerivedData since wiping the backend?

Comment: I am testing on real devices. I deinstalled the app -> all clientside data should be reset.